# Windows 10 turned all gray without color filer

Tags: windows, windows-10

After pushing some shortcuts my windows turned completely gray. No color filter is enabled, no high contrast mode either. Is it an easter egg?

Answer (score 2):

It might be happened due to an outdated display adapter.
Make sure that your device's display adapter is up-to-date. You may check for the latest driver from the display adapter manufacturer's website.
Also try pressing Windows + Ctrl + C keys from the keyboard to turn back the PC's color. However, if nothing happens, make sure that your display driver is up-to-date

Answer (score 2):

The answer was surprising: it was the F.Lux new feature enabled via `windows` + `end`

Comment: Interesting! I have Flux but stopped messing with that color option after it made my screen go completely black. And a friendly reminder that it's acceptable and encouraged to mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

I think that you triggered a setting to help with color blindness.

Try Windows key + Ctrl + C

I found more information at [this site](https://www.brucebnews.com/2017/11/look-at-the-red-flowers-windows-10-now-includes-help-for-color-blindness/)